# Line break in hex changes from 0A to 0D0A

Tags: mysql, hex

I have developed a simple web app to add/edit/delete some records. For history purposes I am saving the changes history in one auxiliary 'changes' table with the following structure:

```
id
old_value
new_value
date
...
```

After opening and saving one record of my app withoud changing anything a new record in the history has been created, where apparently old_value and new_value are the same. However, checking the hex value of the strings, I can see that my record initially had `0A` in the line break (initial value in the database) and the new record has `0D0A` as line break (after showing in an HTML form and saving without any changes). Of course, both are different for PHP `!=` function so the difference in history is created.

My questions are:

1. A proper string stored in MySQL should have `0D0A` or just `0A` for new lines?
2. Initial value (`0A`) comes from a Microsoft Excel migrated to MySQL, why it only had `0A` in the line breaks?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *After opening and saving one record of my app withoud changing anything*: If nothing is changed, why are you saving it in the first place? Also, what should be stored in the DB depends on the OS you're using. Windows uses 0x0D0A, *nix systems use 0x0A. If you open the file in a Windows-based editor like Notepad, it will use 0x0D0A.

Comment: `0D0A` or `0A` not **are** but **are interpretated as**. I.e. it depends on a tool which visualizes or processes the text.

Comment: @KenWhite About _opening and saving one record of my app withoud changing anything_ of course it was another part of the registry what I changed, but being a historical record for one part of the form I didn't change surprised me.

Comment: About the other comments, my database should store `0x0D0A` or `0x0A`? I need it consistent, so that fictious changes are not recordad, as PHP's function string1 != string2 returns TRUE and therefore a historical record is created.

Comment: By the way, instead of checkinh hex value through phpMyAdmin I have generated an .sql file and in Notepad++ in my Windows system this is how it appears:
string1: \n
string2: \r\n

Comment: I have applied a QUICK PATCH in the database:

`UPDATE table
SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, "\n", "\r\n")`

This way, functionality is the same and edits in other columns don't create false changes in my `column` data.